# Angular Updating http service post code to Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to add a service from some code I found which posts some data but some of the code is already old and my angular version is 5.

Here is the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  postResponse: any ;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  insertData() {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:1234/dus/mypage.php', JSON.stringify({firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith333'}),{ headers: headers})
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res: '') => this.postResponse = res);
  }

}
```

I'm having trouble with headers and RequestOptions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http, https://angular.io/api/http/Http. Now that you know where the documentation is, you can at least try something on your own.

Comment: Just having trouble with Headers and RequestOptions

Comment: You don't need any of this. You didn't need it with Http either. Read the documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Adding header like this--

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json');
```

You don't need options variable if you are passing headers directly in your http post call.

Comment: This is completely unnecessary. Sending an object to post() will automtically serialize it to JSON and add this header. https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: It's also wrong, BTW, since HttpClient doesn't expect Headers, but HttpHeaders.

Comment: take a look at this link https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#append. http headers are immutable, so every time it return a new instance and applies the changes.

Comment: Yes, I know that. How is it relevant to your answer, which doesn't use HttpHeaders at all (which makes it wrong)?